# read data from datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two entities: User(id, name, groupId) and Group(id, title). I want to display all users in my grid: |id|name|group title|. What is the best way to get users with group titles? (using low level API and without denormalizing)

Answer (score 0):

Without denormalizing or changing your model definitions, there's really only one way: get all of the users, make a set of their groupIds and use a query to get Group entity. Unfortunately, your system won't scale very well because this approach doesn't leverage datastore well.

One thing that you could do to improve performance and scalability we be to store the actual datastore Id of the Group entity and then use `Group.get_by_id()` to get all of the entities at once rather than as separate queries. This leverages the fact that `get_by_id()` (like `get_by_key_name()` is faster than querying on an entity value and you can also request all of the ids with a single call, dramatically-reducing the amount of work that needs to be done by AppEngine.